# Compiling a TOR static Binary for Windows

Tags: windows, gcc, compilation, cygwin, tor

I've recently found some information on Creating a Static TOR Binary and I have got one version up and running but this is only for the Linux OS's. Is there anyone that could enlighten me on how to compile a static binary for windows OS ?
There are 2 options I could work with:

1. Build a TOR static Binary for Windows
2. Create a Cygwin layer to make the Linux static binary work on Windows.

Which one is more suggested? 
Any other suggestions?

Please help me out and give me some guidelines in how create this, thanks!